How to change parameter names in spring boot before controller
How to change parameter names in Spring boot before controllers?
I want to change name of parameters in HttpServletRequest in Spring boot...
for example, I want to change these parameters
search[value]=test
search[regex]=false

to these parameters:
search.value=test
search.regex=false

and use @ModelAttribute in my controller
for example:
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> search(
    @ModelAttribute Search search
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
//    enter code here
}

Is it possible in Spring or Spring boot?
My Search model is
public static class Search {
    private String value;
    private boolean regex;

    // ... getters and setters (optional)
}

thanks

Intercept incoming requests with a custom HttpServletRequestWrapper and modify the request parameters there.

We know @ModelAttribute can understand search.value but can't understand search[value]. Both of them are correct in Javascript but not in Java. We have to use HttpServletRequestWrapper. That's right, but how to remove search[value] to prevent next errors? Thanks anyway

modify search[value] by replacing it in  request.getParameterMap() method

We can't change it. I need to get a solution. But thanks a lot
